# SQL Server, Lat and Lon query

Tags: sql, sql-server, latitude-longitude

I'm running a query to get all locations in a table within a 15 mile radius. The query can take up to 15 seconds.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rmiukpostcodes
WHERE 3963.191 * ACOS( (SIN(PI()*50.8320711166062/180)*SIN(PI()*latitude/180))+(COS(PI()*50.8320711166062/180)*cos(PI()*latitude/180)*COS(PI()*longitude/180-PI()*-0.207548227491786/180))) < = 5
```

Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: if you are using SQL Server 2008, there has native lat/lon support, may faster. Search "SPATIAL DATA SUPPORT" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434647.aspx

Comment: Indexes on latitude and longitude columns?

Comment: Hi, It's SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3):

Use [spatial data types](http://jasonfollas.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/sql-server-2008-spatial-data-part-1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit here from using a computed persisted column.  You're causing a table/index scan because of your `WHERE` clause, I believe.

Capture your execution plan.  Try adding the computed column and alter your `SELECT` query.

Comment: But the where clause will change every time - There's nothing that can be computed is there?

Comment: @MattFellows The OP can surely group the `latitude` and `longitude` portions of the equation into a computed column

Comment: I guess he could pre-calculate SIN(PI()*latitude/180) and cos(PI()*latitude/180) - but that is all as everything else is a function of the require lat and long

Answer (score 0):

Your query reads every row in the table.  Use some [SARGABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) filter criteria and an index.

For example: before you run the query, precompute the max/min lat or long and use it.

```
WHERE
  codes.Lat BETWEEN @minLat AND @maxLat
  AND YourDistanceCalcHere(codes.Lat, codes.Long)
```

Then, an index on codes (Lat) would help the query

Comment: This is entirely un-useful - you've basically told him to do what he's asked how to do.  The OP asked what he could do to make it faster, i assume he knows that filtering the query more would do that, but how can he do that based on his query - i.e. find all rows within n miles of a lat and long.

Comment: @MattFellows if you assume he knows sargable criteria, of course my answer is useless. I assume the opposite, directed by the evidence (the query).

Comment: You are missing the point - there's no way to restrict that down if the only criteria is distance. There's no evidence of a lack of knowledge of anything.

Comment: @MattFellows no way?  Maybe no ideal way, but there is a way... see edit.